# Button in html table doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, html-table

I places a button in a html table and its disabled by default also I places an images as the button background, but this doesn't show up.

Could I please get help with this.

This is the html that I am using:

```
<table border="0" id="seat_btn">
<tr>
    <td><button class="btn" id="a1" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;" onclick="alert('a1눌렸어요')"><img class="btn-img" src="seat1.png"></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="a2" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat2.png"></button></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="a3" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat3.png"></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="a4" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat4.png"></button></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="a5" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat5.png"></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="a6" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat6.png"></button></td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="btn" id="b1" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat1.png"></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="b2" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat2.png"></button></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="b3" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat3.png"></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="b4" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat4.png"></button></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="b5" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat5.png"></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="b6" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat6.png"></button></td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="btn" id="c1" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat1.png"></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="c2" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat2.png"></button></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="c3" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat3.png"></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="c4" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat4.png"></button></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="c5" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat5.png"></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" id="c6" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="seat6.png"></button></td>   
  </tr>   
  <tr><td><button type="submit" value="1" style="height:100px;" onclick="alert('안뇽')">dfdf</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: wait for a sec :) im lookin for it

Comment: and i want to tell that this code is for making 'movie theater seat'

Answer (score 1):

if you just want create buttons inside a table use something like this

```html
<table><td>
 <a href="your tag here">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/8/8800.png">
 </a>
</td>
<td>
 <a href="your tag2 here">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/69/69407.png">
 </a>

</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[onclick button change image](https://codepen.io/DannaB67/pen/vZyLEo/)  https://codepen.io/DannaB67/pen/vZyLEo

I hope this will work for you. Also, you don't have to use "button" and then "img" in the button. You may only use the "button" with several CSS classes, like class="seat btn-img". Check the link.

```
 <script type="javascript">
    $(".seat").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active")  ; 
    })
 </script>

<style type="text/css">
  .seat{
    background-image: 
    url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sympletts-free-
    sampler/128/tv-
    seat-128.png");
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
  }

 .seat.active{
    background-image: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mobile-
    friendly-ui/100/close-128.png");
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
  }
  </style>
```

Add this to the head of your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and these are your buttons:

```
<button class="seat btn-img" id="a1" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white; " onclick="#"></button>
   <button class="seat btn-img" id="a2" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white; " onclick="#"></button>
   <button class="seat btn-img" id="a3" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white; " onclick="#"></button>
   <button class="seat btn-img" id="a4" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white; " onclick="#"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".btn").click(function(){

$(this).find("img").prop('src', 'http://hdwallpaperfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Big-Waves-Fantasy-Image-HD.jpg')

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" id="seat_btn">
<tr>
<td>
<button class="btn" id="a1" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;" onclick="alert('a1눌렸어요')"><img class="btn-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"></button></td>
<td><button class="btn" id="a2" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"></button></td>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td><button class="btn" id="a3" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"></button></td>
<td><button class="btn" id="a4" type="submit" style="border:0px; background-color:white;"><img class="btn-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"></button></td>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mr7d22gw/1/